# How to find the next month and current month datetime in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to find the next month and current month Datetime in python

I have a dataframe which has date columns and i need to filter the values based on todays date.

if todays date is less than 15, i need all row values starting from **current month (2019-08-01 00:00:00)**

if todays date is >=15, i need all row values starting from **next month(2019-09-01 00:00:00)**

**Dataframe**:

```
      PC  GEO        Month             Values
      A   IN    2019-08-01 00:00:00     1
      B   IN    2019-08-02 00:00:00     1
      C   IN    2019-09-14 00:00:00     1
      D   IN    2019-10-01 00:00:00     1
      E   IN    2019-07-01 00:00:00     1
```

if today's date is < 15

```
      PC  GEO        Month             Values
      A   IN    2019-08-01 00:00:00     1
      B   IN    2019-08-02 00:00:00     1
      C   IN    2019-09-14 00:00:00     1
      D   IN    2019-10-01 00:00:00     1
```

if today's date is >= 15

```
      PC  GEO        Month             Values
      C   IN    2019-09-14 00:00:00     1
      D   IN    2019-10-01 00:00:00     1
```

I am passing todays date as below
  
  `dat = date.today()`
   
 `dat = dat.strftime("%d")`
    
`dat = int(dat)`

Comment: have you check `pandas.dateoffset?` looks like you need `df[df.Month.month == date.today().month ]` or `df[df.Month.month == (datetime.date.today() + pd.DateOffset(months=1)).month]`

Comment: @jezrael... bro can u help me out... i have added a comment to your answer... please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])

#get today timestamp
dat = pd.to_datetime('now')
print (dat)
2019-08-27 13:40:54.272257

#convert datetime to month periods
per = df['Month'].dt.to_period('m')
#convert timestamp to period
today_per = dat.to_period('m')


#compare day and filter
if dat.day < 15:
    df = df[per >= today_per]
    print (df)
else:
    df = df[per > today_per]
    print (df)
      PC GEO      Month  Values
    2  C  IN 2019-09-14       1
    3  D  IN 2019-10-01       1
```

Test with values `<15`:

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])

dat = pd.to_datetime('2019-08-02')
print (dat)
2019-08-02 00:00:00

per = df['Month'].dt.to_period('m')
today_per = dat.to_period('m')

if dat.day < 15:
    df = df[per >= today_per]
    print (df)

      PC GEO      Month  Values
    0  A  IN 2019-08-01       1
    1  B  IN 2019-08-02       1
    2  C  IN 2019-09-14       1
    3  D  IN 2019-10-01       1

    else:
        df = df[per > today_per]
```

Comment: bro can u also let me know how to drop the rows of **month** like ...<br> `if dat.day <15 : df1 = df1.drop(df1['Month']  >= today_per )`
<br>  `if dat.day >15 : df1 = df1.drop(df1['Month']  > today_per )`